# Differentiate between user type and primitives

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, usertype

I'm trying to differentiate between user types and primitive types in a variadic template.

I have tried overloading binary operator, but that only says that there's no fitting overload for 'user types'...

```
template <typename T>
void PrintParams(T t)
{
    if (IsAUserType)
        std::cout << typeid(t).name();
    else
                std::cout << t;
}

    template <typename First, typename... Rest>
void PrintParams(First first, Rest... rest)
{
    if (IsAUserType)
        std::cout << typeid(first).name();
    else
                std::cout << first;

    PrintParams(rest...);
}

    // If you know what to do with this, then that would also be very helpful...
    //Overload << operator for user types
//template <typename T>
//friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, T t)
//{
            // 
    //if (std::is_fundamental<t>::value)
        //std::clog << t;
    //else
        //std::clog << typeid(t).name();
//}
```

expected result for input like (class test, 3.4, "string") would be 
"test3.4string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split your single argument function up in two and use SFINAE to enable the correct one depending on if the argument is a fundamental type or not:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void PrintParams(T t) {
    std::cout << t;
}

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void PrintParams(T t) {
    std::cout << typeid(t).name();
}

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void PrintParams(First first, Rest... rest) {
    PrintParams(first);  // ... and call the single argument version here
    std::cout << ",";
    PrintParams(rest...);
}
```

---

Another way would be to check if the type supports streaming using `operator<<` instead of checking that it's a fundamental type. That would make streaming work for classes (like `std::string` and user defined ones too).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>
```

```
// SFINAE support

namespace detail {
    template<class>
    struct sfinae_true : std::true_type {};

    template<class S, class T>
    static auto test_lshift(int)
        -> sfinae_true<decltype(std::declval<S>() << std::declval<T>())>;

    template<class S, class T>
    static auto test_lshift(long) -> std::false_type;
} // namespace detail

template<class T>
struct has_ostream : decltype(detail::test_lshift<std::ostream, T>(0)) {};
```

```
// using the SFINAE support stuff

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<has_ostream<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void PrintParams(const T& t) {
    std::cout << "Type: " << typeid(t).name() << "\n"
              << " supports operator<<   Value = " << t << "\n";
}

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!has_ostream<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void PrintParams(const T& t) {
    std::cout << "Type: " << typeid(t).name() << "\n"
              << " does NOT support operator<<\n";
}

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void PrintParams(First first, Rest... rest) {
    PrintParams(first);
    PrintParams(rest...);
}
```

```
// example classes

class Foo { // will not support streaming
    int x = 5;
};

class Bar { // this should support streaming
    int x = 10;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Bar&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Bar& b) {
    return os << b.x;
}
```

```
// testing

int main() {
    int i = 2;
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    std::string s = "Hello world";

    PrintParams(i, f, b, s);
}
```

Possible output:

```
Type: i
 supports operator<<   Value = 2
Type: 3Foo
 does NOT support operator<<
Type: 3Bar
 supports operator<<   Value = 10
Type: NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
 supports operator<<   Value = Hello world
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll test this asap. I'll get back to you!

Comment: @chillisko You are welcome. I added a more complete version which should support user defined types with streaming too.

Comment: This worked! And SO MUCH thanks for the ostream support answer aswell. It was just what I was trying to achieve. I hope this will help someone else also.

Answer (score 0):

I think `std::is_class` can replace your `IsAUserType`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class

Comment: EDIT: This gives error: << no operator found which takes a right hand operand of type class. :/ 

For the line cout << first

Comment: Try `if constexpr (std::is_class ...` (but this is C++17).

Comment: I can only use C++11 max. :/

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data types include integer , character , void , float etc..which are defined already inside the language i.e , user can use these data types without defining them inside the language. 
User defined data types are the data types which user have to define while or before using them.

Comment: Yes, I knew this already. Thanks anyway, this may help a beginner.
I was trying to differentiate between them in variadic templates in order to change application output depending on what type the parameter is.